# ViewModel null when Activity started from IntentFilter

Tags: android-activity, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to use NFC along with MvvmCross. So I have created an `IntentFilter` which looks like this:

```
[IntentFilter(new[]{"android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"}, 
    Categories = new[] {"android.intent.category.DEFAULT"},
    DataScheme = "bksv-resource", DataHost = "nmt")]
```

And in `OnResume` I am looking for `Intent` Actions of the type `NfcAdapter.ActionNdefDiscovered`. What happens is when NDEF is discovered, the Activity gets created and an Intent is set with the data inside. All this works fine in an `Activity`, however problems occur when wanting to use an `MvxActivity` or `MvxFragmentActivity`.

Problem is, when the `MvxActivity` gets recreated the `base.OnCreate()` call gives no `ViewModel` back and no reason is given, only output like this is shown:

```
mvx:Diagnostic:  6.09 Loading new ViewModel from Intent with Extras
mvx:Warning:  6.13 ViewModel not loaded for view ScanView
```

I am not entirely sure how the `ViewModel` is found for a `View`, however, in this case it seems not to be found. Why could that be? Do I need a custom app start or something?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand here what "recreated" means? Does it mean a new one is created and given savedInstanceState from an old one? Or does it just mean a new one is created?

Comment: `OnCreate` gets called, so I assume it is a entirely new `Acitivty`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MvvmCross picks up its ViewModel navigation information from the passed in `Intent`

You can:

- see how MvvmCross creates it's `Intent`s in: [MvxAndroidViewsContainer.cs#L120](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxAndroidViewsContainer.cs#L120)
- see how MvvmCross gets the information back out in: [MvxAndroidViewsContainer.cs#L87](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxAndroidViewsContainer.cs#L87)

If you are using a custom non-MvvmCross `Intent` then MvvmCross obviously won't be able to pick up its navigation information - so you'll have to work out a way to create the ViewModel yourself.

Comment: Ah. Makes sense. I've solved this by creating the ViewModel like this: var loaderService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();
      ViewModel = (ScanViewModel)loaderService.LoadViewModel(
                    new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof(ScanViewModel), null, null, null), null);