# Xamarin.Android mvvmcross app crashes when launching with intent filter

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, intentfilter

When opening up the android application via a link, the android application crashes, with a `NullReferenceExcetpion`.

The `NRE` happens in the `base.OnCreate(bundle)` method.  The base is of type `MvxFragmentCompatActivity`.  I have also tried this with a standard `MvxActivity`.

I have had a look at the following questions (but to no avail)

- [ViewModel null when Activity started from IntentFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547700/viewmodel-null-when-activity-started-from-intentfilter)
- [Open MvvmCross app via link with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288628/open-mvvmcross-app-via-link-with-data/35289859)

The Activity

```cs
[Activity(...)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, DataScheme = "https", DataHost = "my.link.com", DataPathPrefix = "/some/path/", Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
public class MyActivity : MvxFragmentCompatActivity<MyViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        //Other code here (never reached when triggered by IntentFilter)
    }
}
```

The stack trace

```
Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):   at MvvmCross.Platform.Mvx.Resolve[TService] () <0x9dcd9978 + 0x00038> in <filename unknown>:0 
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):   at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContextHelpers.Current[T] () <0x9dcd9930 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0 
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):   at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContextHelpers.Current () <0x9dcd9910 + 0x0000f> in <filename unknown>:0 
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):   at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxLayoutInflater.Inflate (Int32 resource, Android.Views.ViewGroup root, Boolean attachToRoot) <0x9dcd7800 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0 
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):   at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.n_Inflate_ILandroid_view_ViewGroup_Z (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, Int32 resource, IntPtr native_root, Boolean attachToRoot) <0x9dcd7780 + 0x00063> in <filename unknown>:0 
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:a2381224-dbcc-42b0-9aea-a687067e2004 (intptr,intptr,int,intptr,bool)
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x9dcdc6b8 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0 
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) <0x9dd046f0 + 0x000b3> in <filename unknown>:0 
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):   at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) <0x9dcd6608 + 0x0014f> in <filename unknown>:0 
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):   at MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat.MvxEventSourceAppCompatActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) <0x9dcd5850 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0 
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):   at MyMobileApp.Droid.Activities.MyActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) <0x9dcd5400 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0 
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):   at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) <0x9dcd5380 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:0 
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:e50a07b6-601f-425e-bac2-dd61e65b301f (intptr,intptr,intptr)
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):     at md5af86c8db51f1d1641c99147539ead00a.MyActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):     at md5af86c8db51f1d1641c99147539ead00a.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:43)
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-15 12:37:45.361 E/AndroidRuntime(26519):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this has to do with: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1192

Try something like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    var setup = MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(ApplicationContext);
    setup.EnsureInitialized();

    base.OnCreate(bundle);
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this did solve the issue.  Along with me moving some of the service registrations around.

Comment: Fixed my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54690561/imvxappstart-related-crash-with-application-oncreate-overridden) too. Thanks.