# IMvxAppStart related crash with Application.OnCreate overridden

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, oncreate

The error:

> `MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException`: Failed to resolve type `MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxAppStart` occurred

when tried to override `Application.OnCreate`

```cs
[Application]
public class RemoteApplication : MvxAndroidApplication<Setup, Core.App>
{
    public RemoteApplication(IntPtr reference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) :
        base(reference, transfer) { }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by **@Martijn00** advice from [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36647066/2346621)

```cs
public override void OnCreate()
{
    MvxAndroidSetupSingleton
        .EnsureSingletonAvailable(ApplicationContext)
        .EnsureInitialized();

    base.OnCreate();
}
```

**6.2.3**
`MvvmCross` update from `6.2.2` to `6.2.3` fixed the crash, but the app stuck on `Splash Screen` then. So only `EnsureInitialized()` fixed it entirely.